# Streaming uploads using Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to stream an "infinite" (i.e. continuous) amount of data using HTTP Post. Basically, I want to send the POST request header and then stream the content (where the content length is unknown). I looked through http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/ and it seems to have the facility. The one question I have is it says in the document " To stream and upload, simply provide a file-like object for your body". What does "file-like" object mean? The data I wish to stream comes from a sensor. How do I implement a "file-like" object which will read data from the sensor and pass it to the caller?

Sorry about my ignorance here but I am feeling my way through python (i.e. learning as I go along. hmm.. looks like a snake. It feels slithery. Trying to avoid the business end of the critter... :-) ).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Ranga.

Comment: You might want to try out a websocket?

Comment: Yes I think I'll go the route of websockets. It seems to achieve the effect I want. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to give you an answer so you could close your question:

It sounds like what you're really looking for is python websockets. Internally, you make a HTTP request to upgrade the connection to a websocket, and after the handshake you are free to stream data both ways. Python makes this easy, [for example](http://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/introducing-flask-sockets):

```
from flask import Flask 

from flask_sockets import Sockets

app = Flask(__name__) 
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/echo') 
def echo_socket(ws): 
    while True: 
        message = ws.receive() 
        ws.send(message)

@app.route('/') 
def hello(): 
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Websockets do support full duplex communication, but you seem only interested in the server-to-client part. In that case you can just stream data using `ws.send()`. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it should provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A file-like object is an object with a "read" method that accept a size and returns a binary data buffer for the next chunk of data.

One example that looks like that is indeed, the file object, if you want to read from the filesystem.

Another common case is the [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) class, which reads and writes to a buffer.

In your case, you would need to implement a "file-like object" by yourself, which would simply read from the sensor.

```
class Sensor(object):
    def __init__(self, sensor_thing)
        self.sensor_thing = sensor_thing

    def read(self, size):
        return self.convert_to_binary(self.sensor_thing.read_from_sensor())

    def convert_to_binary(self, sensor_data)
        ....
```

Comment: There might actually be an issue, if it reads without placing size, it will expect "all the data", so when you return, it would think it has everything and it will break. In order to make sure it doesn't do that (sorry, can't change the library :), I removed the default value for size

Comment: Apparently websockets will do the job for me. Flask has support for websockets and there is an available websocket client in python.